# Linear Mixed Effects Models for Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm, truncated-normal-distribution

I would like to analyze amplitude differences of discrete oscillations that were detected in a time-series using a thresholding method between three different conditions. The number of discrete events are unbalanced due to the nature of the design and grouped by subjects and blocks. From what I know about the amplitude data I would expect a normal distribution. Because of the two last statements I thought a linear mixed effects model would be appropriate since it handles unbalanced and grouped data such as mine. Now the problem is that the amplitude is no longer normally distributed but truncated normal due to the thresholding procedure. Here are two questions that arose from that:

- I would expect that fitting a linear mixed effects model to this data would systematically overestimate the mean of the different conditions and hence the difference between conditions would remain the same, i.e. similar if the distribution weren't truncated. Would you say it's appropriate to still use a linear mixed effects model in this case?
- Are there any R or python packages that implement mixed effects models dealing with truncated normal distributions? I only saw that the glmmADMB package states that a truncated gaussian would be coming soon.

Comment: I think [GAMLSS](https://www.gamlss.com/) should be able to do this. Truncated distributions are implemented in the [`gamlss.tr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss.tr/index.html) package.

Comment: Thanks @COOLSerdash, I've tried to use gamlss in combination with gamlss.tr to create a truncated gaussian, however, I get convergence issues. Despite the convergence issues I get a reasonable estimate for the mean of the distribution, but the standard deviation seems to be way off. I couldn't find that much on how to deal with these convergence issues in gamlss. Maybe you've got a reference to point me towards?

Comment: Hi again, I just realized that the link function of the sigma parameter is a different one than the mu parameter's. So transforming sigma back to the response scale makes sense and the parameters fit the distribution pretty well, however, if I retrieve the fitted values from the model using e.g. `fitted(model)` they have a completely different distribution than what I have specified. Are there any peculiarities that I am overlooking?

Comment: I'd use `predict` to recover the fitted values. There, you can specify what part you want to recover (e.g. the mean) and on what scale. If you type `type = "response"` you should get the values on your originale scale.

Comment: @COOLSerdash, I've tried that as well, but `predict` with `type = "response"` gives me the same output as `fitted`.

Comment: Thanks. Without any reproducible example, all I can do is speculate at this point.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package that has many special families already implemented, and also gives you the opportunity to define your own distribution for your data. More specifically, have a look in the following vignettes:

- [Zero-Inflated and Two-Part Mixed models](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html)
- [Custom Mixed Models](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Custom_Models.html)

Comment: Hey @Dimitris, thanks a lot for your answer, but I think my statistics understanding is too limited to come up in a reasonable time with a truncated gaussian custom model, which is why I'll first try the gamlss package.

Comment: This is now available in the family object `censored.normal()`.