# Lmer model fails normality and homogeneity of the residuals; model-predicted lines are not great. Some predictors might not be linear. What can I do?

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, nonlinear-regression, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption

**CONTEXT:**
I gathered data from 1000 participants in five different countries, with each line in my dataset corresponding to a unique participant. My study examines how much individuals support the idea of their government being more open to their input related to policy making, with the dependent variable being the mean score of several Likert items (rated from 1 to 7) per participant. I used various predictors including dummy variables, mean scales, and single items that were all mean centered, including the country variable.

**MAIN MODEL**

```r
m_lmer <- lmer(support_scale ~ 1 + satisfaction_item + 
                awareness_scale + trust_item + just_scale + 
                gender_dummy +(1|country), 
                data = df, REML=FALSE, 
                control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", 
                optCtrl=list(maxfun=50000)))
```

Although all predictors were significant, the **model violated assumptions of normality and homogeneity of residuals**.

```r
> check_heteroscedasticity(m_lmer)
Warning: Heteroscedasticity (non-constant error variance) detected (p < .001).

> check_normality(m_lmer)
Warning: Non-normality of residuals detected (p < .001).

> check_collinearity(m_lmer)
# Check for Multicollinearity
Low Correlation
```

[image]
[image]

**INFORMATION ABOUT DISTRIBUTIONS**

It's worth noting that some predictors have outliers, but I decided not to remove them in this context. Also, the `fitdist()` function classified the dependent variable and many of the predictors as having `Weibull` distributions, while some predictors had `lnorm` and `gamma` distributions.

Distribution of my dependent variable:

[image]

**GAM MODEL THAT I TRIED AS ALTERNATIVE**

I tried a gam model with smooth terms and two of my predictors seemed to be non-linear, but the gam model also seems to fail the homogeneity of the residuals and did not accept country as a random effect with bs = 're'.

```r
m_gam <- gam(support_scale ~ 1 + satisfaction_item + 
             s(awareness_scale, bs="cr") + trust_item + s(just_scale, 
             bs="cr") + gender_dummy, 
             data = df, method = 'REML') 

                              k'  edf k-index p-value
s(awareness_scale)          9.00 3.76    0.99    0.32
s(just_scale)               9.00 5.64    0.99    0.29

> check_heteroscedasticity(m_gam)
Warning: Heteroscedasticity (non-constant error variance) detected (p < .001).

> performance::compare_performance(m_lmer, m_rlmer,m_gam, rank = TRUE)
# Comparison of Model Performance Indices

Name      |           Model |  RMSE | Sigma | Performance-Score
---------------------------------------------------------------
m_gam   |             gam | 1.050 | 1.065 |            57.13%
m_rlmer |        rlmerMod | 1.072 | 1.017 |            50.00%
m_lmer  | lmerModLmerTest | 1.071 | 1.073 |             3.40%
```

**QUESTIONS**

Despite attempting to log transform the dependent variable, the assumptions of normality and homogeneity of residuals continued to fail.

What should I do? It's not ok using these models because of the failed homogeneity, right?

Does `rlmer` handle non-constant and non-normal residuals?

Or should I try bayesian approach and specify the distributions of all the predictors in the priors?

**EDIT:** In response to @GeorgeSavva

I couldn't run the GLMMADAPTIVE's approach:

```r
m_glmm <- mixed_model(fixed = support_scale ~ 1 + satisfaction_item + 
            awareness_scale + trust_item + just_scale + gender_dummy,  
            random = ~ 1 | country, data = df, 
            family = censored.normal())

Error in y[, 2L] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

With `truncreg` the residuals look like this:
[image]

```r
m_trunc <- truncreg(support_scale ~ 1 + satisfaction_item + 
              awareness_scale + trust_item + just_scale + 
              gender_dummy, data = df, point = 7, direction = "right")
```

With GAMLSS's approach, the model seems to be better but the deviation is still present.

```r
m_gamlss <- gamlss(support_scale ~ 1 + satisfaction_item + 
                   cs(awareness_scale) + trust_item + cs(just_scale) +  
                   gender_dummy + random(factor(country)), data = df)
```

[image]
[image]

Are these deviations problematic in a GAMLSS model?

Comment: Not a full answer to your question but since your response looks like a truncated normal (which makes sense given its origin) I wonder if methods for truncated distributions would work better.  There seems to be a few options for truncated normal mixed models in R (eg https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406014/linear-mixed-effects-models-for-truncated-normal-distribution)  Also, since you only have five countries consider whether a mixed model is necessary?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva Thank you! I tried GLMMadpative, GAMLSS, and truncreg. The residuals were still non-constant. Are any of the models more forgiving in the failure of these assumptions?

Comment: Since your outcome is bounded above I don't see how your residuals are ever going to be normally distributed.  I don't know what the diagnostics should look like for those models.  Another thought, don't be too alarmed by diagnostics returning very low p-values.  The original lmer didn't look terrible to me (in terms of interpreting effects) so it would interesting to get other's thoughts on that.

Comment: Could you consider summing rather than averaging the Likert scale items? Then the resulting sum score could be easily modeled with semi-parametric ordinal regression model like the proportional odds or ordered probit model. These models have no issue with ceiling or floor effects. The R package 'ordinal' can fit these models and handle random effects, though personally with only 5 countries I personally think you may as well treat country as a fixed effect (the results will likely be similar). Happy to expand into an answer if useful.

Comment: Thank you, @Lachlan, for your idea! Using a sum to compute the dependent variable in a gamlss model with skewnormal family still showed deviation. But usign the sum variable and a beta-binomial family in brms greatly improved the model. Do you know of any packages that can run such models, other than Bayesian ones? I also experimented with using individual items as within-participant repeated measures, which yielded the best fit so far. However, I am unsure if this is a valid approach or a valid family. I am open to the possibility of not using countries as a random effect.

Comment: In terms of likelihood function, I still think it would be worth trying an ordinal regression model with the sum score as the outcome. In brms you can fit these with family = cumulative("probit"), for example. And the interpretation is relatively simple. An ordered probit model will give effect sizes on the scale of the latent normally distributed variable (i.e., receptiveness). For non-bayesian methods, the R package ordinal can fit these models with simple random effects.